# Generate authentication token to be used with Wowza CDN Cloud

Tags: xpages, video.js, wowza

I need to generate a authentication token to secure stream from the Wowza CDN.  I like to do this in server base javascript.  I'm working on Domino 10 xpages server and working with videojs.  Looking for how to get started and any sources that would help.

Comment: What authentication token do you mean? Something like Wrench or is that different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wowza authentication token seams to be an Hash hmac of the information that is needed to authenticate the user.
According to this
https://www.wowza.com/docs/protect-a-wowza-cdn-on-fastly-stream-target-with-token-authentication-in-wowza-streaming-cloud

This is an example how to create these using Javascript
https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#js